# Resusing method calculation values

Tags: java, methods, return-value

I am new to methods and am trying to find a way to take the totals from the `calculateTotalStay` method and `calculateMiscCharges` method and add them together in the `calculateTotalCharges` method, I can't figure out how to reuse the values calculated I've tried loads of things including makings a variable = the method name but that caused the first method to display more than once, any help appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Wk6Lab1Ex1 {

public static  double standardCharge;
public static  double miscCharges;
public static double totalCharges=standardCharge+miscCharges;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int patientCount = 1;

    calculateTotalCharges();

}


/**
 * A method to calculate to read in the number of days spent in the clinic and return the figure calculated
 * @return
 */
public static double calculateStayCharges() {
    String message = "Please enter the number of days you spent in the clinic";
    int daysInClinic=readPositiveInt(message);

    double standardCharge=300*daysInClinic;

    System.out.println("Your standard charges are" + " " + standardCharge);
    return standardCharge;


}
/**
 * A method to read in and calculate all the miscellaneous charges and total them
 * @return the total for all misc fees
 */
public static double calculateMiscCharges() {

    String message = "Please enter your medication charges";
    double medicationCharges=readPositiveDouble(message);

    String message1 = "Please enter your surgical charges";
    double surgicalCharges=readPositiveDouble(message1);

    String message2 = "Please enter your physical rehabilitation charges";
    double physicalRehabiliation=readPositiveDouble(message2);

    String message3 = "Please enter your lab fees";
    double labFees=readPositiveDouble(message3);

    double miscCharges=medicationCharges+surgicalCharges+labFees+physicalRehabiliation;

    System.out.println("Your miscellaneous charges are" + " " + miscCharges);


    return miscCharges;


}

/**
 * A method to take the stay charges and misc charges and total them
 * @return the total treatment cost
 */
public static  double calculateTotalCharges() {

    calculateStayCharges();

    calculateMiscCharges();



    int standardCharge = 0;
    int miscCharges = 0;
    double totalCharges=standardCharge+miscCharges;

    System.out.println("Your total charges are" + " " + totalCharges);

    return totalCharges;


}
/**
 * Ensuring the number entered for amount of days is an integer
 * @param prompt the enter number of days prompt
 * @return the int value for number of days
 */

public static int readInt(String prompt)
{
    // Create a scanner object for input from the console window
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // boolean flag which is used to control the
    // data validation loop

    boolean numGood = false; // Assume the worst   
    do
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);  // ask for the value
        if(!keyboard.hasNextInt()) // check if what's in the keyboard buffer is not a double
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter an  value!"); // display an error message
            keyboard.nextLine(); // consume the bad value entered
        }
        else
            numGood = true; // value entered is good
    } while(!numGood);
    // at this point we know the value in the
    // keyboard buffer is numeric so we can go ahead and
    // return it.
    return keyboard.nextInt();
}
/**
 * The readPositiveInt method reads a positive int value
 * from the console window and will display an appropriate
 * error message if a non-positive int value is entered.
 * @param prompt A prompt to request the user to enter a value
 * @return The positive int value entered.
 */
public static int readPositiveInt(String prompt)
{
    int value;
    do
    {
        value = readInt(prompt); // ask for and read an double value
        if (value <0) // check if the value entered is less than 0
            // display an error message
            System.out.println("Error - you must enter a positive numeric value greater than zero!");
    } while (value <0);
    // at this point we know the value entered is positive
    // so return it
    return value;
}
/**
 * readDouble ensures the values entered for fees are doubles
 * @param prompt asks user to enter various fees
 * @return returns the double value
 */
public static double readDouble(String prompt)
{
    // Create a scanner object for input from the console window
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // boolean flag which is used to control the
    // data validation loop

    boolean numGood = false; // Assume the worst   
    do
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);  // ask for the value
        if(!keyboard.hasNextDouble()) // check if what's in the keyboard buffer is not a double
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter an  value!"); // display an error message
            keyboard.nextLine(); // consume the bad value entered
        }
        else
            numGood = true; // value entered is good
    } while(!numGood);
    // at this point we know the value in the
    // keyboard buffer is numeric so we can go ahead and
    // return it.
    return keyboard.nextDouble();
}
/**
 * The readPositiveDouble method reads a positive double value
 * from the console window and will display an appropriate
 * error message if a non-positive double value is entered.
 * @param prompt A prompt to request the user to enter a value
 * @return The positive double value entered.
 */
public static double readPositiveDouble(String prompt)
{
    double value;
    do
    {
        value = readDouble(prompt); // ask for and read an double value
        if (value <0) // check if the value entered is less than 0
            // display an error message
            System.out.println("Error - you must enter a positive numeric value!");
    } while (value <0);
    // at this point we know the value entered is positive
    // so return it
    return value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the return value of the methods to a variable, but make sure you call each method only once:

```
public static  double calculateTotalCharges() {
    double standardCharge = calculateStayCharges();
    double miscCharges = calculateMiscCharges();
    double totalCharges=standardCharge+miscCharges;
    System.out.println("Your total charges are" + " " + totalCharges);
    return totalCharges;
}
```

Also, I changed the type of the variables `standardCharge` and `miscCharges` to `double` to match the return type of the methods. I think this will match your expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much total is working now I'm not great at programming but i'm usually not far off been at that ages now

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer helps you, the best way of saying thanks in S.O is accepting and/or upvoting the answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method that returns a value as if it were a void method will result in the loss of the value returned by the method. By using the values in an expression and assigning they will be kept. Try this:

```
/**
 * A method to take the stay charges and misc charges and total them
 * @return the total treatment cost
 */
public static  double calculateTotalCharges() {

    int standardCharge = 0;
    int miscCharges = 0;
    double totalCharges=calculateStayCharges()+calculateMiscCharges();

    System.out.println("Your total charges are" + " " + totalCharges);

    return totalCharges;


}
```